# External power supply on a 2nd Atmel

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, power

This [video](https://youtu.be/muP1dp73Mdg?t=476) is about using external power supply on a 2nd Atmel.

I saw in the picture the Ground and Vcc connection like this:

[image]

The Arduino Uno is connected to the ground (from USB ?) and the - of 5V power supply is connected to this ground, too.

I am surprised.  I don't understand why the Arduino Uno's ground (from the USB?) is connected to the battery's ground because they are different grounds.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the ground of the Arduino Uno and that of the USB are identical.

I understood that we can connect the grounds together but there must not be a possible circuit between the positive terminals.

We have 2 electrical circuits here.

The ground connected to the negative terminal of the battery consists in obtaining a reference frame and being able to measure + 5V (to program the Atmel, see Kartman's remark.)

I have attached a diagram that explains this (*Engineering Circuit Analysis - 8th edition* - by William Hayt (Author), Jack Kemmerly (Author), Steven Durbin (Author).)

[image]